# multiply Python's time object?

Tags: python, time

I want to estimate remaining time required to execute a script written in python that has a (nested) loop, and inside the loop there's a test that can take a few seconds to execute. The test will execute a few Thousand times, so it will take multiple hours before it finishes. By measuring how long one test takes, I want to estimate how many hours it will take before the script finishes.

```
from time import time, strftime

for i in range(n):
    t = time()      # current time
    ...very complicated test that can take quite a few seconds that uses i 
    elapsed = time() - t    #calculate time required to execute test
```

When i try to multipliy the time that it takes to execute the test once

```
remaining_time = elapsed * (n - i)
remaining_time_s = strftime("%H:%M:%S", remaining_time)
print("estimated remaining time:", remaining_time)
```

the call to `strftime` gives:

```
TypeError: Tuple or struct_time argument require
```

Why is a multiple of time() not a time object?

Comment: I believe that by multiplying the time, you convert to an int / float. Can you print out `remainingTime` after the line `remainingTime = elapsed*(n-i)` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referencing `time.time()` and not `datetime.time()` (because you can't multiply in the latter case), `time.time()` is not a time object.  It's a `float`.  `datetime.strftime` is looking for a `datetime` object.

If you look at your `remainingTime`, you'll notice it should actually be a `float` that is much smaller than you'd expect.  That's because by doing `time() - t` you actually stripped most of the timestamp information that allows you to convert back to `datetime`.

In short, don't use `strftime` to convert a `float`.  You could do this instead:

```
for i in range(n):
    t = datetime.datetime.now()

    ... some codes ...

    elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - t   # gives you a timedelta object

    elapsed *= n-1                          # still a timedelta object

    print(elapsed)

    # 0:00:42.276000
```

Comment: if OP wants to, they can convert floats to `struct_time` using the `gmtime` or `localtime` functions, as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this from the `time` module, then `t` is going to be a float:

```
>>> import time
>>> t = time.time()
>>> type(t)
<type 'float'>
>>> time.time()
1550765873.363
```

This means that `elapsed` is presumably a float too, as is `remainingTime`.   But `strftime` needs to be fed a datetime.date object.

```
>>> t = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> type(t)
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> print(datetime.datetime.strftime(t, "%H:%M:%S"))
11:16:57
```

Also, note the order of the arguments.

If you have an elapsed time in seconds that you want to convert to H:M:S, you could do something like this:

```
H = remaining // 3600
M = (remaining - (3600*H)) // 60
S = remaining - (3600*H) - (60*M)
print("%d:%d:%d" % (H, M, S))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `elapsed`, and your `remaining_time` values are just floats, not `struct_time`s.  You can convert them with [`gmtime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.gmtime) or [`localtime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.localtime):

```
>>> from time import time, localtime, strftime
>>> t = time()
>>> elapsed = time() - t
>>> strftime("%H:%M:%S", localtime(t))
'08:22:03'
>>> strftime("%H:%M:%S", localtime(elapsed + t))
'08:22:25'
```

You may want to switch to `datetime` objects, which can be subtracted (yielding `timedelta` objects), and all these can be manipulated easily:

```
>>> n = datetime.now()
>>> m = datetime.now()
>>> m - n
datetime.timedelta(0, 4, 316830)
>>> delta = m - n
>>> delta * 5
datetime.timedelta(0, 21, 584150)
>>> m + delta
datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 21, 8, 28, 24, 943365)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `elapsed` value is a float. You can convert it to a `datetime.timedelta` object and print it out. Doing it this way won't allow you to specify the string format though.

```
from datetime import timedelta

remainingTime = timedelta(seconds=(elapsed*(n-i)))
print("estimated remaining time: {}".format(str(remainingTime))
```